# Loop through XElement and remove some tags

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, xelement

please consider this code:

```
public static XElement ToXElement<T>(this object obj,List<string> JustThisProperties)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, obj);
            var xml = XElement.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
            xml.Attributes().Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration).Remove();
            foreach (var item in xml.Elements())
            {
                if (JustThisProperties.Where(o=>o == item.Name.ToString()).Any() == false)
                {
                    xml.Elements(item.Name.ToString()).Remove();
                }
            }

            return xml;
        }
    }
}
```

and XML:

```
<Log>
   <tbl>
       <ID>21</ID>
       <MasterID>3</MasterID>
       <C_2>1</C_2>
       <C_3>1</C_3>
       <C_4>1</C_4>
       <C_5>2000</C_5>
       <C_6>2</C_6>
       <C_7>2</C_7>
       <C_8>2</C_8>
       <C_9>2</C_9>
       <C_10>2</C_10>
    </tb>
</Log>
```

I want to serialize just some properties. For example when above `XML` generated I want to remove all tags except `{C_2,C_9,C_10}`. The problem is when it remove `C_2` because `XML` has been change it did not continue the `foreach` and break it. How I can remove some tags from an `XElement`?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Remove` extension method on `IEnumerable<T> where T : XNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
xml.Elements()
   .Where(item => !JustThisProperties.Contains(item.Name.ToString()))
   .Remove();
```

(You might want to make `JustThisProperties` an `IEnumerable<XName>`, which would let you get rid of the `ToString()` call.)